# PHP Update sql shows blank page

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

PHP Update sql shows blank page

Here's the code in update.

```
<?php

 if (isset($POST['update'])){
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $course = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['course']);
    $age = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['age']);
    $department = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['department']);
    $dateadded = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dateadded']);
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE student SET name='$name', course='$course', age='$age', department='$department', dateadded='$dateadded' WHERE id=$id");

    $_SESSION['message'] = "Updated!";
    header('location: index.php');
  }

?>
```

After that it shows only the blank page.

Comment: Your code contains too many errors and there are too many unknowns.

Comment: Indentation edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the mistake you made here 
**"if (isset($POST['update'])** "
it should be " **"if(isset($_POST['update']))"** 
thats why its displaying a blank page.

Comment: Thanks i've seen the error

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have a typo in line three. The statement is never true as this global variable is wrong thus False. It needs to be $_POST.

Instead of

> if (isset($POST['update']))

use this

> if (isset($_POST['update']))

Comment: Thanks i've seen the error